# Documentation - Vandalism / deletion

Tags: discussion, documentation

I wrote an example in the closed beta for RecyclerView interactions.

Here is the [changelog of interactions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/revisions/169?exampleId=689).

I will go through the steps of changes with my understanding of what is happening.

1. I create the example.
2. Patrick edits it helpfully.
3. Sunday edits it heavily according to a suggestion (most of the code is gone, seems more like vandalism at this stage).
4. Joshua edits the mess the make it more readable.
5. Fahad deletes the example, because it is obviously unusable at this stage.

I would suggest to revert the example to before Sunday edited it.

Is there a procedure for this?

Edit: looking through the topic, I noticed my other example was deleted at point in this interaction too `GridLayoutManager with OnClickListener and dynamic dataset`.

Edit2: Here is the [link to the changelog of the GridLayoutManager example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/revisions/169?exampleId=690) I added. No reason for deletion, other than the example isn't helpful. Surely it is?

Comment: I can't judge the validity of the revision, but the improvement request was "I'd remove the Activity bits and just show the Recyclerview initialization, Adapter and ViewHolder code so the example is a bit shorter and more focused on the actual topic." Did the revision do that? I don't know what to think of deletions that can be done by two people for the only reason that "this example is not helpful". Quite frustrating.

Comment: If you look through the revision, it is catastrophic! It is edited to the point that `onBindViewHolder` does literally nothing. Really, the error lies with the reviewer. Allowing such a change with only one person reviewing it is an error I think.