# Topics being blown away without explanation or comment available

Tags: discussion, documentation

Maybe I am missing something, but I can't seem to find a way to view history for a tag so I can see reasons for a whole section being deleted.

There is not even any notification. If you contributed you just will see that suddenly all your reputation earned is gone.

Why is there no alert, or any way to see why this happened? And why is such a delete happening with a few people's opinion on whether it should stay, and all of the people that contributed to it and upvoted on the sections posts are disregarded and can't comment or see the reason?

Quite discouraging to want to contribute knowing that a whole section can be blown away without notice or chance to discuss such a proposal.

Edit: To clarify, the problem is why is there no notification of such a deletion that someone contributed to, and no way for someone to comment on a deletion request or see the reason for the deletion. You randomly lose rep, for no given reason or explanation, and can't comment on such a removal. Normally if your post on QA is going to be deleted or closed you can see this and chime in.

Comment: That's been asked already today, can't find it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addressing Documentation #RepGateApocalypse](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse)

Comment: @CodeCaster: Maybe too many posts since yesterday? I already gave up reading...

Comment: Maybe not, but I feel like you are trying to communicate 3 problems at once

Comment: This happened to me twice today: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328877/documentation-vandalism-deletion - First one someone defaced the example to the point it was useless, then it was flagged as being useless and it was deleted. Second one, someone just straight out deleted it for being unhelpful. I personally would beg to differ, but of course I would be biased.

Comment: @Braiam Not a duplicate. That is a completely different question. Please read what you linked.

Comment: Can you clarify then what you want? That people isn't able to edit your examples? That your reputation isn't lost due the example being deleted? That you get notifications when someone flags your example? 1 isn't going to happen, 2 nobody is sure if reps is even a good idea at this point, 3 I'm unable to know if there's a notifications for authors of an example, but you can subscribe yourself to different requests for action (req. topic, NI, and proposed changes). Of course there's a activity log for each tag.

Comment: I'm one of the people directly affected by this. I wrote a topic in "Python Hidden Features" and the topic was entirely deleted (I suspect because it was too board). But I get no notification of why it was deleted, initially I thought it was something wrong with my post instead of the topic itself. There should be some mechanism to see the reason for deletion, like for questions.

Comment: @Braiam checkout nico's comment it explains what I am talking about.

Comment: @Braiam what is your opinion of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/revisions/169?exampleId=690 - it is my opinion there is too little oversight for the deletion of someones work.

Comment: @Knossos wow that is crazy, all it took was one person to hit delete, and one other to hit approve. That is all it takes to remove someones documentation and work, and they don't even get notified. Crazy

Comment: @Knossos I can't have a opinion of something I don't know of, but aren't examples to the point? What's the topic about? RecyclerView? How I eat that?

Comment: Alright, if you aren't familiar with the topic then that makes it more difficult. But as ComputerLocus said, it takes 2 people to delete. It is one drone reviewer away from being a docs-mjolnir. That is mostly what my question to you was about though. Less about the quality of the code. If the issue was that the code wasn't encapsulated enough, then I would be happy with a request to do so. But outright deletion?

Comment: @Knossos related [Who can delete a documentation example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328813)

Comment: @Braiam Doesn't that seem wrong to you? So little input and room for discussion and it get be removed. On something like Wikipedia it takes a lot more discussion to delete something. It should not be this easy, and not have any room for discussion.

Comment: This is the current page notifying a topic deletion: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/946/hidden-features). It lists 3 possible reasons without listing either the people that voted or the reason for deletion.

Comment: I agree that there should be notification of some kind when a topic you've created or a proposal you've submitted is deleted. 

This lack of notification seems in line with the other lack of notification throughout the site, however; you aren't notified when your questions or answers are deleted on the Q&A site, either.

Comment: The thing is that stuff is **day 2**! I don't necessarily agree with the current status quo, but I'm not sure if the other side is having a bigger plan in mind of how docs should work... basically, both of you have a tool box with the same tools, but building different things and getting in the way of each other. Better is to hop into a chat room of the tag in question and ask for guidance about what would be useful to this point, it could be that your examples are ok, just in the wrong topic, or the topic is just ambiguous. [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328804/792066)

Comment: @nico actually you can http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/32807, btw, the whole process was handled by 4 users, most of them with some positive interaction on the python tag.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks that gives a little more information namely the users involved, but it would be more helpful imo if there a specific reason given (in this case "Off-topic").

Comment: @nico I did approve of this edit even though I regretted it afterwards. The reason why I approved was because 50% of the examples were already covered in seperate topics and almost all of them were copied (with some alteration) from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python. The reason why I regret it is: Not all of the examples were bad and should have been moved instead of deleted. Long story short: I'm sorry that I approved this deletion without commenting.

Comment: I also opened a question to make deletion harder especially because I felt so bad afterwards: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328911/make-it-easier-to-restore-a-deleted-topic-in-documentation

Comment: There's no rollback mechanism (at least, not that I can find), so it's not really clear what one is supposed to do in the situation [that @Knossos mentioned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328997/topics-being-blown-away-without-explanation-or-comment-available?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment370822_328997), where the example is rendered unacceptable by a bad edit. I'm not saying deletion is the right way to solve it, but I think it's worth pointing out that it seems to be the only way to "repair" mistakes like that.

Comment: I agree. It really is discouraging when you put in the effort to write something informative and someone can just destroy the example and subsequently it gets deleted. In SO, if there is a bad edit (usually it would be smartly filtered out by reviewers) there is a rollback button to get back the original content. Docs really need this rollback function.