# How to mark a docs change as invalid and revert it?

Tags: support, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/39415

This is a common misconception which actually seems to be unmentioned in [standard java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Both edits for that particular example are wrong. Can I somehow revert that edit or do I have to do another edit to revert the changes?

Comment: Shows how broken the approval system is. The change was approved by a 380 rep user who has a [tag:java] answer score of 10.

Comment: I think the real issue here is the unfit approval process rather than than the shoddy edit(s)

Comment: So easy to get crap into the system, but tools and UI to deal with that crap once it exists are horrible

Comment: @charlietfl why would you ever want to remove content from the glorious new wing of the site? We don't incentivize the blind and brainless flooding of the empty pages with crap in order to *deal with it* later. Sheesh.

Answer (score 4):

You can propose a rollback by going through the history of a topic.

[image]

Rollbacks are edits that are reviewed like other changes, in order to preserve history and not break links.

Comment: As UX feedback, I'd like to remark that I went looking for this feature and [had come to the conclusion that it didn't exist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328997/topics-being-blown-away-without-explanation-or-comment-available#comment372222_328997). I expected it to be somewhere either in this top-level view or "View Edit", based on its location in Q&A revision histories.